# Unable to upload a chunked file using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a chunk upload for a file using PHP and JS. The chunk process is happening,

However, the file is not getting uploaded to the directory.

My Code goes as:

**Index.php**

```
<HTML>
<head>
<script src="plupload/js/plupload.full.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        var path = "plupload/js/`";
        var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
          browse_button: 'pickfiles',
          container: document.getElementById('container'),
          url: 'testupload.php',
          chunk_size: '1000kb',
          max_retries: 2,
          filters: {
            max_file_size: '30mb',
            mime_types: [{title: "Video", extensions: "mp4,3gp,mov"}]
          },
          init: {
            PostInit: function () {
              document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML = '';
            },
            FilesAdded: function (up, files) {
              plupload.each(files, function (file) {
                document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML += '<div id="' + file.id + '">' + file.name + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ') <b></b></div>';
              });
              uploader.start();
            },
            UploadProgress: function (up, file) {
              document.getElementById(file.id).getElementsByTagName('b')[0].innerHTML = '<span>' + file.percent + "%</span>";
            },
            Error: function (up, err) {
              // DO YOUR ERROR HANDLING!
              console.log(err);
            }
          }
        });
        uploader.init();
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <form action="insert.php" method="post" >
  <div id="container">
    <span id="pickfiles" style="font-weight:600;">Click <span> Here </span> to Upload Full Video</span>
  </div>
  <div id="filelist" style="color:red">Your browser doesn't support HTML5 upload.</div>
    <span class="pure-form-message"> * required</span>

  <input type="text" name="inp1" />
  <input type="text" name="inp2" />

  <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

**testupload.php**

```
<?php
// RESPONSE FUNCTION
function verbose($ok=1,$info=""){
  // THROW A 400 ERROR ON FAILURE
  if ($ok==0) { http_response_code(400); }
  die(json_encode(["ok"=>$ok, "info"=>$info]));
}
// INVALID UPLOAD
if (empty($_FILES) || $_FILES['file']['error']) {
  verbose(0, "Failed to move uploaded file.");
}
// THE UPLOAD DESITINATION - CHANGE THIS TO YOUR OWN
$filePath = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "uploads";
if (!file_exists($filePath)) { 
  if (!mkdir($filePath, 0777, true)) {
    verbose(0, "Failed to create $filePath");
  }
}
$fileName = isset($_REQUEST["name"]) ? $_REQUEST["name"] : $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$filePath = $filePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;
// DEAL WITH CHUNKS
$chunk = isset($_REQUEST["chunk"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunk"]) : 0;
$chunks = isset($_REQUEST["chunks"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunks"]) : 0;
$out = @fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");
if ($out) {
  $in = @fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "rb");
  if ($in) {
    while ($buff = fread($in, 4096)) { fwrite($out, $buff); }
  } else {
    verbose(0, "Failed to open input stream");
  }
  @fclose($in);
  @fclose($out);
  @unlink($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
} else {
  verbose(0, "Failed to open output stream");
}
// CHECK IF FILE HAS BEEN UPLOADED
if (!$chunks || $chunk == $chunks - 1) {
  rename("{$filePath}.part", $filePath);
}
verbose(1, "Upload OK");
?>
```

**insert.php**

```
$inp1 = $_POST['inp1'];
$inp2 = $_POST['inp2'];
$file2= isset($_REQUEST["name"]) ? $_REQUEST["name"] : $_FILES["file"]["name"];

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO table (inp1, inp2, file)
            VALUES ('$inp1', '$inp2', '$file2')";
            if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) { } else { }
```

Please note that :

- The Chunking process is happening, which i can see in [image: Inspect -> Network]
- Why isn't the chunked file getting uploaded to the directory.
- How can i submit the name of the uploaded file to form in above index.php

Any help is greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

first of all, change your js script of your plugin

**index.html**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plupload/3.1.2/plupload.full.min.js" integrity="sha512-+F2bTlYeSZrUs0uNo8OsYlE4tbdEoGp3Hhur4V+4o4nmsljKKDgCexLpqc5mERevdiOqthT4SVL+SHhz4lyfcA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

and below code to your js code

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        var path = "plupload/js/`";
        var fileInputBox = document.querySelector("#videoTitle");
        var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
          browse_button: 'pickfiles',
          container: document.getElementById('container'),
          url: 'testupload.php',
          chunk_size: '1000kb',
          max_retries: 2,
          filters: {
            max_file_size: '30mb',
            mime_types: [{title: "Video", extensions: "mp4,3gp,mov"}]
          },
          init: {
            PostInit: function () {
              document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML = '';
            },
            FilesAdded: function (up, files) {
              plupload.each(files, function (file) {
                document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML += '<div id="' + file.id + '">' + file.name + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ') <b></b></div>';
                fileInputBox.value = file.name;
              });
              uploader.start();
            },
            UploadProgress: function (up, file) {
              document.getElementById(file.id).getElementsByTagName('b')[0].innerHTML = '<span>' + file.percent + "%</span>";
            },
            Error: function (up, err) {
              // DO YOUR ERROR HANDLING!
              console.log(err);
            }
          }
        });
        uploader.init();
      });
```

and you want to add the video title to your PHP variable then you can add some js changes

**testupload.php**

```
// RESPONSE FUNCTION
function verbose($ok=1,$info=""){
    // THROW A 400 ERROR ON FAILURE
  if ($ok==0) { http_response_code(400); }
  die(json_encode(["ok"=>$ok, "info"=>$info]));
}
  
  // INVALID UPLOAD
  if (empty($_FILES) || $_FILES['file']['error']) {
    verbose(0, "Failed to move uploaded file.");
  }
  
  // THE UPLOAD DESITINATION - CHANGE THIS TO YOUR OWN
  $filePath = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "uploads";
  if (!file_exists($filePath)) { 
    if (!mkdir($filePath, 0777, true)) {
      verbose(0, "Failed to create $filePath");
    }
  }
  
  $fileName = isset($_REQUEST["name"]) ? $_REQUEST["name"] : $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  $filePath = $filePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;
  // DEAL WITH CHUNKS
  $chunk = isset($_REQUEST["chunk"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunk"]) : 0;
  $chunks = isset($_REQUEST["chunks"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunks"]) : 0;
  $out = @fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");
  if ($out) {
    $in = @fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "rb");
    if ($in) {
      while ($buff = fread($in, 4096)) { fwrite($out, $buff); }
    } else {
      verbose(0, "Failed to open input stream");
    }
    @fclose($in);
    @fclose($out);
    @unlink($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
  } else {
    verbose(0, "Failed to open output stream");
  }
  // CHECK IF FILE HAS BEEN UPLOADED
  if (!$chunks || $chunk == $chunks - 1) {
    rename("{$filePath}.part", $filePath);
  }
  verbose(1, "Upload OK");
```

now you can access the video title from insert.php

**insert.php**

```
$inp1 = $_POST['inp1'];
$inp2 = $_POST['inp2'];
$file2= isset($_REQUEST["videoTitle"]) ? $_REQUEST["videoTitle"] : $_FILES["file"]["name"];

return print_r([
    $inp1,
    $inp2,
    $file2,
]);
```